# how to get the data attribute of parent element even if the child element is clicked

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I'm trying to get the data attribute of a div when clicked in **Backbone events(View)**.

I'm able to achieve this if I click on the div `listItem` but if I was to click on the child element span it will fail because `$(e.target)` will be the span.

So how do I get the data attribute of the parent element, even if the child element is clicked?

```
<div class="listItem" data-showInfo="true">
    <span class="arrow"></span>
</div>

events:{
  "click .listItem": function(e) {

    var $listItem= $(e.target);

    console.log($listItem.data('showInfo'));
  }
}
```

Comment: is your div.listItem in the scope of Backbone View's el ? Just to get clarity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target`, it will be set to the `.listItem` selector independently of the DOM node you click

```
var V = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click .listItem' : function(e) {
            console.log($(e.currentTarget).data('showinfo'));
        }
    }
});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/QyP3Z/

Comment: how to do the same for vanilla JS ?

Comment: @PawanDeore Probably something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58855262/1071630

Answer (score 6):

You can do it like this:

```
$('.arrow').click(function(){
alert($(this).parent().attr('data-showInfo'));
});
```

Your example is in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6gQTA/)

Answer (score 2):

```
events:{    
    "click .arrow": function(){
        console.log($(this).parent('.listItem').attr('data-showInfo'));
    };
}
```