# Vanilla JavaScript Event Delegation

Tags: javascript

What is the best way ( fastest / proper ) fashion to do event delegation in vanilla js?

For example if I had this in jQuery:

```
$('#main').on('click', '.focused', function(){
    settingsPanel();
});
```

How can I translate that to vanilla js? Perhaps with `.addEventListener()`

The way I can think of doing this is:

```
document.getElementById('main').addEventListener('click', dothis);
function dothis(){
    // now in jQuery
    $(this).children().each(function(){
         if($(this).is('.focused') settingsPanel();
    }); 
 }
```

But that seems inefficient especially if `#main` has many children.

Is this the proper way to do it then?

```
document.getElementById('main').addEventListener('click', doThis);
function doThis(event){
    if($(event.target).is('.focused') || $(event.target).parents().is('.focused') settingsPanel();
}
```

Comment: Start with the `event.target`, see if it matches the selector, and if so, invoke the function. Then iterate up through its ancestors and do the same until you get to the `this` element. You can use `node.matchesSelector()` to do the test, though in some browsers it's implemented with a browser-specific flag, so you'd either need to wrap it in a function, or put the flag method on `Element.prototype.matchesSelector`

Comment: Would suggest you post that as an answer.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli: I don't like posting answers. I'll let someone else get the rep. Feel free if you'd like.

Comment: @cookiemonster why would I find the child element and then go up?

Comment: Relevant: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.matches

Comment: @MrGuru: Because that's how event delegation works. You have to see if any node in the element hierarchy matches the selector, starting with the element where the event originates and stopping at the element you bound the handler to.

Comment: @MrGuru: If you're implementing event delegation, then you know that the `event.target` was the element clicked, so that's the first one to test. But it could be that the event bubbled up from the `event.target` and encountered a different element that matches, so you'd usually want to include that. That's basically what jQuery does. Like `<div class="focused"><span>click me</span></div>`. The `event.target` will be the `span`, so we iterate up to find the `.focused`.

Comment: @cookiemonster I can use jQuery everywhere except listening for the event. Is the way I put in my question the proper way to do it?

Comment: @MrGuru: The handler should be invoked once for each ancestor that matches the selector, and the ancestors should stop before the `this` element. So maybe `$(event.target).parentsUntil(this, ".focused").each(settingsPanel)`

Comment: I guess the jQuery implementation is pretty good :)

Comment: [Relevant David Walsh article](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)

Comment: Closely related: [Attach event to dynamic elements in javascript](/q/34896106/4642212).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**[I've come up with a simple solution](https://gist.github.com/evenicoulddoit/9769f78e9a6f359c4561)** which seems to work rather well (legacy IE support notwithstanding). Here we extend the `EventTarget`'s prototype to provide a `delegateEventListener` method which works using the following syntax:

```
EventTarget.delegateEventListener(string event, string toFind, function fn)
```

I've created a fairly complex **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ianclark001/Dq8W8/)** to demonstrate it in action, where we delegate all events for the green elements. Stopping propagation continues to work and you can access what should be the `event.currentTarget` through `this` (as with jQuery).

Here is the solution in full:

```
(function(document, EventTarget) {
  var elementProto = window.Element.prototype,
      matchesFn = elementProto.matches;

  /* Check various vendor-prefixed versions of Element.matches */
  if(!matchesFn) {
    ['webkit', 'ms', 'moz'].some(function(prefix) {
      var prefixedFn = prefix + 'MatchesSelector';
      if(elementProto.hasOwnProperty(prefixedFn)) {
        matchesFn = elementProto[prefixedFn];
        return true;
      }
    });
  }

  /* Traverse DOM from event target up to parent, searching for selector */
  function passedThrough(event, selector, stopAt) {
    var currentNode = event.target;

    while(true) {
      if(matchesFn.call(currentNode, selector)) {
        return currentNode;
      }
      else if(currentNode != stopAt && currentNode != document.body) {
        currentNode = currentNode.parentNode;
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  /* Extend the EventTarget prototype to add a delegateEventListener() event */
  EventTarget.prototype.delegateEventListener = function(eName, toFind, fn) {
    this.addEventListener(eName, function(event) {
      var found = passedThrough(event, toFind, event.currentTarget);

      if(found) {
        // Execute the callback with the context set to the found element
        // jQuery goes way further, it even has it's own event object
        fn.call(found, event);
      }
    });
  };

}(window.document, window.EventTarget || window.Element));
```

Comment: You ought to check first for the standard unprefixed version.

Comment: @gilly3 I should also calculate it once rather then every time. I'll update

Comment: I would recommend using `window.Node` instead of `window.Element`. The document itself inherits from `Node`, getting the functionality to work in IE (which doesn't have `EventTarget`).

Answer (score 19):

Rather than mutating the built-in prototypes (which leads to fragile code and can often break things), just check if the clicked element has a `.closest` element which matches the selector you want. If it does, call the function you want to invoke. For example, to translate

```
$('#main').on('click', '.focused', function(){
    settingsPanel();
});
```

out of jQuery, use:

```
document.querySelector('#main').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.closest('#main .focused')) {
    settingsPanel();
  }
});
```

Unless the inner selector may also exist as a parent element (which is probably pretty unusual), it's sufficient to pass the inner selector alone to `.closest` (eg, `.closest('.focused')`).

When using this sort of pattern, to keep things compact, I often put the main part of the code below an early return, eg:

```
document.querySelector('#main').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (!e.target.closest('.focused')) {
    return;
  }
  // code of settingsPanel here, if it isn't too long
});
```

Live demo:

```js
document.querySelector('#outer').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (!e.target.closest('#inner')) {
    return;
  }
  console.log('vanilla');
});

$('#outer').on('click', '#inner', () => {
  console.log('jQuery');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    inner
    <div id="nested">
      nested
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [`document.querySelector` is not going to fly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20495960/673826) if DOM is not loaded yet. This is not quite delegation.

Comment: Sure it is - just like OP's jQuery code of `$('#main').on('click', '.focused', function(){` is delegating clicks inside `#main` to `#main`'s click listener, my code is doing the same thing. This is the technique to use if `#main`'s children are dynamic (like if `#main` is a todo list container). If `#main` itself may not exist, that's a different situation, and would of course require delegating the events to an outer parent.

Comment: My bad.. indeed OP's case would work. I should have elaborated as I was looking for solution compatible with [Turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#observing-navigation-events). It removes everything but document and window. I ended up using only `.matches` with complete selector and without `querySelector` on document like in your last example.

Comment: The second snippet uses a simple `target.matches()`, which isn't the same as `.closest()` in that it would require the event to fire on that element directly and not on one of its descendants. I guess this isn't intended.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar solution to achieve event delegation.
It makes use of the Array-functions `slice`, `reverse`, `filter` and `forEach`.

- `slice` converts the NodeList from the query into an array, which must be done before it is allowed to reverse the list.
- `reverse` inverts the array (making the final traversion start as close to the event-target as possible.
- `filter` checks which elements contain `event.target`.
- `forEach` calls the provided handler for each element from the filtered result as long as the handler does not return `false`.

The function returns the created delegate function, which makes it possible to remove the listener later.
Note that the native `event.stopPropagation()` does not stop the traversing through `validElements`, because the bubbling phase has already traversed up to the delegating element.

```
function delegateEventListener(element, eventType, childSelector, handler) {
    function delegate(event){
        var bubble;
        var validElements=[].slice.call(this.querySelectorAll(childSelector)).reverse().filter(function(matchedElement){
            return matchedElement.contains(event.target);
        });
        validElements.forEach(function(validElement){
            if(bubble===undefined||bubble!==false)bubble=handler.call(validElement,event);
        });
    }
    element.addEventListener(eventType,delegate);
    return delegate;
}
```

Although it is not recommended to extend native prototypes, this function can be added to the prototype for `EventTarget` (or `Node` in IE). When doing so, replace `element` with `this` within the function and remove the corresponding parameter ( `EventTarget.prototype.delegateEventListener = function(eventType, childSelector, handler){...}` ).

Answer (score 0):

### Delegated events

**Event delegation** is used when in need to execute a function when existent or dynamic elements (added to the DOM in the future) receive an Event.
The strategy is to assign to event listener to a known **static parent** and follow this **rules**:

- **use `evt.target.closest(".dynamic")` to get the desired dynamic child**
- use `evt.currentTarget` to get the *`#staticParent`* **parent** delegator
- use `evt.target` to get the ***exact* clicked Element** (WARNING! This might also be a descendant element, not necessarily the `.dynamic` one)

**Snippet sample:**

```js
document.querySelector("#staticParent").addEventListener("click", (evt) => {

  const elChild = evt.target.closest(".dynamic");

  if ( !elChild ) return; // do nothing.

  console.log("Do something with elChild Element here");

});
```

Full example with dynamic elements:

```js
// DOM utility functions:

const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);


// Delegated events
el("#staticParent").addEventListener("click", (evt) => {

  const elDelegator = evt.currentTarget;
  const elChild = evt.target.closest(".dynamicChild");
  const elTarget = evt.target;

  console.clear();
  console.log(`Clicked:
    currentTarget: ${elDelegator.tagName}
    target.closest: ${elChild?.tagName}
    target: ${elTarget.tagName}`)

  if (!elChild) return; // Do nothing.

  // Else, .dynamicChild is clicked! Do something:
  console.log("Yey! .dynamicChild is clicked!")
});

// Insert child element dynamically
setTimeout(() => {
  el("#staticParent").append(elNew("article", {
    className: "dynamicChild",
    innerHTML: `Click here!!! I'm added dynamically! <span>Some child icon</span>`
  }))
}, 1500);
```

```css
#staticParent {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.dynamicChild {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.dynamicChild span {
  background: gold;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<section id="staticParent">Click here or...</section>
```

### Direct events

Alternatively, you could attach a click handler directly on the child - upon creation:

```js
// DOM utility functions:

const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);

// Create new comment with Direct events:
const newComment = (text) => elNew("article", {
  className: "dynamicChild",
  title: "Click me!",
  textContent: text,
  onclick() {
    console.log(`Clicked: ${this.textContent}`);
  },
});

// 
el("#add").addEventListener("click", () => {
  el("#staticParent").append(newComment(Date.now()))
});
```

```css
#staticParent {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.dynamicChild {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<section id="staticParent"></section>
<button type="button" id="add">Add new</button>
```

Resources:

- [Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)
- [Element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)
- [Delegated Events jQuery vs JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14533243/383904)