# event hander Jquery and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, events, tags

Bonjour/ Hi,

J'aimerai savoir comment on traduit le jquery en javascript pour ce type type de fonctionnement car je n'y arrive pas.
I would like to know how to translate jquery into javascript for this type of operation because I can't do it.

Jquery :

```
$("#maDIV").on("click", "[data-action='supprimer']",  function () {
                console.log(" on clique evt");
                 //...
});
```

Javascript ?

```
document.querySelector("#maDIV").addEventListener("click", event => {

                console.log(" on clique evt");
              //..
            }, "[data-action='supprimer']");
```

Cela ne fonctionne pas, quoi qu'il arrive le click sur la div mais bon sur les éléments qui ont le tag "data-action=supprimer".

This doesn't work, whatever happens, click on the div but on the elements that have the tag "data-action=supprimer".

Ce que je souhaite au final, ajouter un événement sur le tag "data-action='supprimer'" sur des sous éléments par rapport à div ou autre élément principale comme cela si j'ajoute un nouvel sous éléments je n'ai pas besoin de redéfinir l'événement.

What I ultimately want is to add an event on the "data-action='delete'" tag on sub-elements in relation to div or other main element like that if I add a new sub-element I don't need it to redefine the event.

Comment: Questions here must be written **only** in English, not two languages.

Comment: event delegation in vanilla javascript, please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72721712/jquery-event-delegation-in-vanilla-js

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and sorry to write in french (my english is bad and I use google traduction)