# Consolidate js code in an php loop. Avoid code repeating

Tags: javascript, php, performance

I generate a list from a DB with php. There are js functions embedded in each line. As you can see in the code, I have to interact the functions and variables to make them work per line.

```
<table id="mySEARCH" class="shoppinglist-content">
<!-- ************************************************************************ shopping list beginn-->
<!-- script test start -->
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['shoppinglist'])){
  $list = $_COOKIE['shoppinglist'];
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `$list`");
  $stmt->execute();
  $x = 0;
  foreach($stmt as $item)
  { $x++;?>
    <tr id="line<?php echo $x;?>" style="opacity: 1.0;">
    <td><button id="activ<?php echo $x;?>" class="btn-hide-row" name='activ' onclick="hiddenLine<?php    echo $x;?>();" value="true"><img class="list-icon" id="visibility<?php echo $x;?>" src="images/icon-invisible.png" /></button></td>
     <form action='calculate.php' method='post'>
     <td class="pcs-unit-list"><?php echo $item['pieces']." ".$item['unit']?></td>
     <td name='item' class="shop-list-item" id="item"><?php echo $item['item']?></td>
     <td class="brand-list"><input type='text' id="brand<?php echo $x;?>" class="brand-list" name='brand' value="<?php echo $item['brand']?>" onkeyup="editSave<?php echo $x;?>(), success()"></td>
     <td class="kind-list"><select class="shoppinglist-kind" name='item-kind' id="item-kind<?php echo $x;?>" onchange="editSave<?php echo $x;?>(), success()">
       <option value=""></option>
       <option value="Gemüse" <?php if($item['kind'] == "Gemüse") echo "selected"?>>Gemüse</option>
       <option value="Obst" <?php if($item['kind'] == "Obst") echo "selected"?>>Obst</option>
       <option value="Fleisch" <?php if($item['kind'] == "Fleisch") echo "selected"?>>Fleisch</option>
       <option value="Fisch" <?php if($item['kind'] == "Fisch") echo "selected"?>>Fisch</option>
       <option value="Getreideprod." <?php if($item['kind'] == "Getreideprod.") echo "selected"?>>Getreideprod.</option>
       <option value="Milchprod." <?php if($item['kind'] == "Milchprod.") echo "selected"?>>Milchprod.</option>
       <option value="Gewürze" <?php if($item['kind'] == "Gewürze") echo "selected"?>>Gewürze</option>
       <option value="Knabbern" <?php if($item['kind'] == "Knabbern") echo "selected"?>>Knabbern</option>
       <option value="Getränke" <?php if($item['kind'] == "Getränke") echo "selected"?>>Getränke</option>
       <option value="Kräuter" <?php if($item['kind'] == "Kräuter") echo "selected"?>>Kräuter</option>
       <option value='Hygiene' <?php if($item['kind'] == "Hygiene") echo "selected"?>>Hygiene</option>
       <option value='Putzen' <?php if($item['kind'] == "Putzen") echo "selected"?>>Putzen</option>
       <option value='Haustier' <?php if($item['kind'] == "Haustier") echo "selected"?>>Haustiere</option>
       <option value='Sonstiges' <?php if($item['kind'] == "Sonstiges") echo "selected"?>>Sonstiges</option>
      </select></td>
      <td class="list-button"><button class='btn-list' name='delete' id="btn-locked-<?php echo $x;?>" value="<?php echo $item['id']?>"><img src='images/trashbox.png'></button></td></form></tr>
      <script>
       function editSave<?php echo $x;?>(){
         var id = <?php echo $item['id']?>;
         var brand = $("#brand<?php echo $x;?>").val();
         var itemKind = $("#item-kind<?php echo $x;?>").val();
         $.post("calculate.php", { save: id, brand: brand, itemkind: itemKind },
         function(data) {
           $('#edit-confirm').html(data);
         });
         }
                                function hiddenLine<?php echo $x;?>() {
                                    var line = document.getElementById("line<?php echo $x;?>");
                                    var activ = document.getElementById("activ<?php echo $x;?>");
                                    var brand = document.getElementById("brand<?php echo $x;?>");
                                    var itemKind = document.getElementById("item-kind<?php echo $x;?>");
                                    var btnLocked = document.getElementById("btn-locked-<?php echo $x;?>");
                                    var btnImage = document.getElementById("visibility<?php echo $x;?>");
                                    if(activ.value == "true"){
                                        activ.value = "false";
                                    }else{
                                        activ.value = "true";
                                    }
                                    if(activ.value == "false"){
                                        line.style.opacity = "0.1";
                                        brand.setAttribute("readonly", "");
                                        itemKind.setAttribute("disabled", "");
                                        btnLocked.setAttribute("disabled", "");
                                        btnImage.setAttribute("src", "images/icon-visible.png");
                                        //createCookie('hide-line-<?php echo $x;?>','false');
                                    }
                                    if(activ.value == "true") {
                                        line.style.opacity = "1.0";
                                        brand.removeAttribute("readonly", "");
                                        itemKind.removeAttribute("disabled", "");
                                        btnLocked.removeAttribute("disabled", "");
                                        btnImage.setAttribute("src", "images/icon-invisible.png");
                                        //createCookie('hide-line-<?php echo $x;?>','true');
                                    }
                                }
                            </script>
                        <?php
                        }
                    }else {
                                                /******************************************************************************** shopping list end****/
                        ?><tr><td></td><td></td><td>Keine Items vorhanden</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><?php
                    }
                ?>
            <!-- script test end -->
            </table>
```

It all works, but is there a way to make it prettier? That I list the functions only 1x under the loop and it still works per line with the right variable values?

Answer (score 0):

1. Bind your event listeners with `addEventListener` and do it once per function using [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508221/vanilla-javascript-event-delegation).
2. Use classes instead of unique IDs
3. Use the [event target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) to find which group of elements is being worked on and then use [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) and [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element/querySelector) to search within that group of elements

For example:

```js
const myEventHandler = event => {
    if (event.target.matches("input[type='checkbox'], select")) {
        const widget = event.target.closest(".my-widget");
        const select = widget.querySelector('select');
        const checkbox = widget.querySelector("input[type='checkbox']");
        const result = widget.querySelector(".result");
        if (checkbox.checked) {
            result.textContent = `Active! Value is ${select.value}`;
            widget.classList.add("active");
        } else {
            result.textContent = "";
            widget.classList.remove("active");
        }
    }
};

addEventListener("change", myEventHandler);
```

```css
.my-widget { border: solid #aaa 1px; padding: 1ex; }
.active { background: #afa; }
.result { min-height: 1.2em; padding: 1ex; }
```

```html
<div class="my-widget">
  <h2>Item 1</h2>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <select>
      <option>1
      <option>2
      <option>3
  </select>
  <div class="result"></div>
</div>

<div class="my-widget">
  <h2>Item 2</h2>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <select>
      <option>1
      <option>2
      <option>3
  </select>
  <div class="result"></div>
</div>

<div class="my-widget">
  <h2>Item 3</h2>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <select>
      <option>1
      <option>2
      <option>3
  </select>
  <div class="result"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, this is helpful, thx!
Could you change your sample with a button instead of input checkbox and post again? It will helpful for me to understand what is important for the trigger and the target. Thx