# EventListener not working properly even though elements are populating correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble with the event listeners within the for loop. Currently, I have the buttons and everything showing up on my page properly. I'm suspecting it may be an issue with the for loop, I cant figure this out since I did something similar on a different project that worked.

```
function generateProjectElements(information) {
  let projectContainer = document.createElement("div");

  for (let x = 0; x < information.length; x++) {
    let projectDiv = document.createElement("div");
    let projectName = document.createElement("h3");
    let buttonsDiv = document.createElement("div");
    let editButton = document.createElement("button");
    let deleteButton = document.createElement("button");

    projectDiv.setAttribute("data-index", x);

    projectDiv.className = "side-project-div";
    buttonsDiv.className = "side-project-btns";
    editButton.className = "edit-btn";
    deleteButton.className = "delete-btn";
    projectName.innerText = information[x];


    editButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log("Hi")
    });

    deleteButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log("Delete!")
    })
    
    projectDiv.appendChild(projectName);
    buttonsDiv.appendChild(editButton);
    buttonsDiv.appendChild(deleteButton);
    projectDiv.appendChild(buttonsDiv);
    
    projectContainer.appendChild(projectDiv);
  }

  return projectContainer.innerHTML;
}


function updateSideMenu(projectArray) {
  let projectCont = document.querySelector(".project-container")
  
  projectCont.innerHTML = generateProjectElements(projectArray)
}
```

When I click them (editButton and deleteButton), its not printing anything out to console.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: The listeners are defined on the DOM elements you have. Which you then just throw away when you return `innerHTML` instead of attaching the elements directly.

Comment: Instead of attaching event listeners in the function, use event delegation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508221/vanilla-javascript-event-delegation

Comment: You should be able to do something like `return projectContainer` and `projectCont.appendChild(generateProjectElements(projectArray))` to deal with HTML elements in the DOM instead of strings.