# Add a text line in php table on button click

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, web-applications

I have a table for vehicle inspections. It has a pass, warning, fail button for each check(each row). It also has a comment button. I would like a text line to popup under the check in the same row once the comment button is clicked. I would also like to have the comment turn red if warning or fail is clicked as it would be required. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

[Click here to see my web app example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfsLj.png)

This is my current code for the table:

```
<div class="container-xxl flex-grow-1 container-p-y">
             
<h2 align="center"><?php echo $appname?></h2><br />
   <div class="form-group">
   <form name="add_name" id="add_name">
                    
   <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
         <?php while ($checks = mysqli_fetch_array($checksqry)) {
         echo '<tr>';
         echo '<td style="width: 20%">'.$checks['check_name'].' <br><br> 

         <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btn[' . $checks['id'] . ']" id="btnpass[' . $checks['id'] . ']" value="Pass">
         <label class="btn rounded-pill btn-outline-success" for="btnpass[' . $checks['id'] . ']">Pass</label>&Tab;&Tab;
                    
         <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btn[' . $checks['id'] . ']" id="btnwarning[' . $checks['id'] . ']" value="Warning">
         <label class="btn rounded-pill btn-outline-warning" for="btnwarning[' . $checks['id'] . ']">Warning</label>&Tab;&Tab;
                    
         <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btn[' . $checks['id'] . ']" id="btnfail[' . $checks['id'] . ']" value="Fail">
         <label class="btn rounded-pill btn-outline-danger" for="btnfail[' . $checks['id'] . ']">Fail</label>&Tab;&Tab;
                    
         <button type="button" name="comment[' . $checks['id'] . ']" id="comment[' . $checks['id'] . ']" class="btn btn-info" style="float: right"><img src="assets/comment.png" width="20px"></button> </td>';
echo '<tr>';}?>
                        
      </table>
   <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
   </div>
   </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Ive tried this for my event listener, but not currently working:

```
document.getElementById ("comment[<?php echo $checks['id']?>]").addEventListener ("click", () => {
                       document.getElementById("commentline[<?php echo $checks['id']?>]").classList.toggle('showMe')
                    }, false);
```

Comment: PHP can create the line in the table, with a class whose CSS has `display: none;`. Then a JavaScript event listener on the checkbox can change the class so it will be displayed, and use another class for the color.

Comment: I understand everything you said, it sounds like the perfect solution. Im just very new to JavaScript, unfortunately. So how do you create an event listener for my situation?

Comment: We can't teach you web application design here. If you don't even know how to create event listeners, you need to start by reading tutorials.

Comment: I was able to create the CSS and the event listener, but it is not working. document.getElementById ("comment[<?php echo $checks['id']?>]").addEventListener ("click", () => {
        document.getElementById("commentline[<?php echo $checks['id']?>]").classList.toggle('showMe')
     }, false);

Comment: Post thhe code in the question, not a comment.

Comment: Use event delegation so you don't have to repeat the code for every element. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508221/vanilla-javascript-event-delegation