Im making a HTML site but ran into a problem with some buttons that i cant seem to solve
So im making a software for a customer to manage products for a machine with 20 lanes but where i've gotten stuck is that i had it working for a while then i did something that i dont remember and now i cant click the lanes anymore. i've tried multiple things like making a new site and i get it to work but something with this piece of code has got me stumped haha
okay so i think i've tracked down the problem to
these lines
// Function to fetch lanes and their active-products from server
  function fetchLanes() {
    fetch('fetch_activeproduct.php')
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Failed to fetch lanes');
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            if (data.success) {
                const lanes = data.lanes;
                updateLanesUI(lanes);
            } else {
                console.error('Error fetching lanes:', data.error);
                alert('Failed to fetch lanes. Please try again later.');
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error fetching lanes:', error);
            alert('Failed to fetch lanes. Please try again later.');
        });
  }

    // Function to update UI with lanes and their active-products
  function updateLanesUI(lanes) {
    const lanesContainer = document.getElementById('lanes');
    lanesContainer.innerHTML = ''; // Clear existing content

    lanes.forEach(lane => {
        const laneElement = document.createElement('div');
        laneElement.classList.add('lane');
        laneElement.textContent = `${lane['active-product']}`;
        lanesContainer.appendChild(laneElement);
        
    });
  }


More specifly the Lanes.forEach(lane=>...... part
Here is the full script so you can understand the code a bit more
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Admin Panel</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: flex;
    }

    .container {
      width: 50%; /* Adjusted width for better layout */
      height: 100vh;
      overflow-y: auto;
      padding: 20px;
      box-sizing: border-box; /* Ensure padding is included in width calculation */
    }

    .lanes-container {
      border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    h2 {
      margin-top: 0;
    }

    .lane {
      border: 1px solid #000;
      padding: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1; /* Ensure lanes are above overlays */
    }

    .product {
      padding: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      border: 1px solid blue;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .search-bar {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .add-product-form,
    .product-form {
      display: none;
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      background-color: #fff;
      padding: 20px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1000; /* Ensure forms are above other elements */
    }

    .add-product-form input,
    .product-form input[type="number"] {
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      width: calc(100% - 40px); /* Adjusted width for input fields */
      padding: 5px;
    }

    .add-product-form button,
    .product-form button {
      background-color: #007bff;
      color: #fff;
      border: none;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .add-product-form button:hover,
    .product-form button:hover {
      background-color: #0056b3; /* Darker shade on hover */
    }

    #close-btn,
    #close-product-form {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      right: 20px;
      color: #555;
      font-size: 20px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    #close-btn:hover,
    #close-product-form:hover {
      color: #333; /* Darker color on hover */
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container lanes-container">
    <h2>Lanes</h2>
    <div id="lanes"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container products-container">
    <h2>Products</h2>
    <div class="search-bar">
      <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search products...">
      <button onclick="searchProducts()">Search</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="filterType">Filter Type:</label>
      <select id="filterType">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="ute">Ute</option>
        <option value="inne">Inne</option>
        <option value="krav">Krav</option>
      </select>
      <label for="filterBrand">Filter Brand:</label>
      <select id="filterBrand">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="garant">Garant</option>
        <option value="stjarnagg">Stjarnagg</option>
        <option value="coop">Coop</option>
        <option value="menigo">Menigo</option>
      </select>
      <button onclick="filterProducts()">Apply Filter</button>
    </div>
    <div id="productsList"></div>
    <button onclick="toggleAddProductForm()">Add Product</button>
    <button id="refresh-list" onclick="fetchProducts()">Refresh List</button>
  </div>
  <div class="add-product-form">
    <h2>Add Product</h2>
    <span id="close-btn" onclick="closeForm()">X</span>
    <input type="text" id="productBrand" placeholder="Product Brand">
    <input type="text" id="productType" placeholder="Product Type">
    <input type="text" id="productAmount" placeholder="Product Amount">
    <input type="text" id="productEggs" placeholder="Product Eggs">
    <button onclick="addProduct()">Add Product</button>
  </div>
  <div class="product-form" id="productSelectionForm">
    <h2>Product Selection</h2>
    <span id="close-product-form" onclick="closeProductForm()">X</span>
    <form id="productSelection" name="productSelection">
      <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
      <input type="number" id="quantity" min="1" value="1">
      <br>
      <label for="packaging">Packaging:</label>
      <select id="packaging">
        <option value="Kartong">Cartons</option>
        <option value="HP">HP</option>
        <option value="PALL">HP</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <button type="button" onclick="selectProduct()">Select</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <script>
    // Global variables
    let selectedProductId = null;

    // Function to generate lanes dynamically
    function generateLanes() {
      const lanesContainer = document.getElementById('lanes');
      lanesContainer.innerHTML = ''; // Clear existing content

      for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        const lane = document.createElement('div');
        lane.classList.add('lane');
        lane.textContent = `Lane ${i}`;
        lane.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
          event.stopPropagation(); // Ensure the event doesn't bubble up
          console.log('Lane clicked:', i);
          assignProductToLane(i);
        });
        lanesContainer.appendChild(lane);
      }
    }

   // Function to assign selected product to a lane
  function assignProductToLane(laneNumber) {
    if (selectedProductId) {
        const selectedProduct = document.querySelector(`.product[data-id="${selectedProductId}"]`);
        if (selectedProduct) {
            const productBrand = selectedProduct.dataset.brand;
            const productType = selectedProduct.dataset.type;
            const productAmount = selectedProduct.dataset.amount;
            const productEggs = selectedProduct.dataset.eggs;

            // Prepare data for AJAX request
            const data = {
                laneId: laneNumber,
                activeProduct: `${productBrand} ${productType} ${productAmount} ${productEggs}`
            };

            // Perform AJAX request to update database
            fetch('update_lane.php', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Failed to update lane');
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(responseData => {
                if (responseData.success) {
                    // Update lane text on UI
                    const lane = document.querySelector(`.lane:nth-child(${laneNumber})`);
                    if (lane) {
                        lane.textContent = `Lane ${laneNumber}: ${data.activeProduct}`;
                        console.log('Lane updated successfully:', responseData);
                    } else {
                        console.error('Lane element not found');
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new Error('Failed to update lane: ' + responseData.error);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error updating lane:', error);
                alert('Failed to update lane. Please try again later.');
            });
        }
    }
  }
    // Function to toggle the visibility of the add product form
    function toggleAddProductForm() {
      const addProductForm = document.querySelector('.add-product-form');
      addProductForm.style.display = addProductForm.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
    }

    // Function to close the Add Product form
    function closeForm() {
      const addProductForm = document.querySelector('.add-product-form');
      addProductForm.style.display = 'none';
    }

 // Function to add a new product
        function addProduct() {
            const productBrand = document.getElementById('productBrand').value.trim();
            const productType = document.getElementById('productType').value.trim();
            const productAmount = document.getElementById('productAmount').value.trim();
            const productEggs = document.getElementById('productEggs').value.trim();

            // Validate inputs
            if (productBrand && productType && productAmount && productEggs) {
                const product = {
                    brand: productBrand,
                    type: productType,
                    amount: productAmount,
                    eggs: productEggs
                };

                // Perform AJAX request to add the product using the PHP script
                fetch('add_test.php', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    body: JSON.stringify(product)
                })
                .then(response => {
                    if (!response.ok) {
                        throw new Error('Failed to add product');
                    }
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(data => {
                    alert('Product added successfully');
                    // Reset the form inputs
                    document.getElementById('productBrand').value = '';
                    document.getElementById('productType').value = '';
                    document.getElementById('productAmount').value = '';
                    document.getElementById('productEggs').value = '';
                    fetchProducts(); // Refresh products list
                    toggleAddProductForm(); // Close the add product form
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error adding product:', error);
                    alert('Failed to add product: ' + error.message);
                });
            } else {
                alert('Please fill out all fields');
            }
        }


    // Function to fetch and display products
        function fetchProducts() {
            fetch('fetch_products.php')
                .then(response => {
                    if (!response.ok) {
                        throw new Error('Failed to fetch products');
                    }
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(products => {
                    const productsList = document.getElementById('productsList');
                    productsList.innerHTML = ''; // Clear the list
                    products.forEach(product => {
                        const productDiv = document.createElement('div');
                        productDiv.classList.add('product');
                        productDiv.dataset.id = product.id; // Set product ID as dataset
                        productDiv.dataset.type = product.type;
                        productDiv.dataset.brand = product.brand;
                        productDiv.dataset.amount = product.amount;
                        productDiv.dataset.eggs = product.eggs;
                        productDiv.textContent = `${product.brand} ${product.type} ${product.amount} ${product.eggs}`;

                        productDiv.addEventListener('click', openProductForm); // Add click event listener
                        productsList.appendChild(productDiv);

                        // Check if this product was previously selected
                        if (product.id === selectedProductId) {
                            productDiv.classList.add('selected');
                        }
                    });
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error fetching products:', error);
                    alert('Failed to fetch products. Please try again later.');
                });
        }

     // Function to open the product selection form
        function openProductForm(event) {
            const productId = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
            const productType = event.currentTarget.dataset.type;
            const productBrand = event.currentTarget.dataset.brand;
            const productAmount = event.currentTarget.dataset.amount;
            const productEggs = event.currentTarget.dataset.eggs;

            const form = document.getElementById('productSelection');
            form.dataset.productId = productId; // Set the product ID on the form
            form.elements['quantity'].value = 1; // Reset quantity to default

            const productForm = document.getElementById('productSelectionForm');
            productForm.style.display = 'block';
        }

        // Function to close the product selection form
        function closeProductForm() {
            const productForm = document.getElementById('productSelectionForm');
            productForm.style.display = 'none';
        }

        // Function to select the product and close the form
        function selectProduct() {
            const form = document.getElementById('productSelection');
            const productId = form.dataset.productId;

            // Highlight the selected product
            const selectedProduct = document.querySelector(`.product[data-id="${productId}"]`);
            if (selectedProduct) {
                // Toggle 'selected' class
                if (selectedProduct.classList.contains('selected')) {
                    selectedProduct.classList.remove('selected');
                    selectedProductId = null; // Clear selectedProductId if deselected
                } else {
                    // Remove 'selected' class from previously selected product if any
                    const previouslySelected = document.querySelector('.product.selected');
                    if (previouslySelected) {
                        previouslySelected.classList.remove('selected');
                    }
                    // Add 'selected' class to the current selected product
                    selectedProduct.classList.add('selected');
                    selectedProductId = productId; // Update selected product ID
                }
            }

      // Close the form after selecting
      closeProductForm();
    }

    // Function to search for products
    function searchProducts() {
      const searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInput').value.toLowerCase();
      const products = document.getElementsByClassName('product');
      Array.from(products).forEach(product => {
        const productName = product.textContent.toLowerCase();
        if (productName.includes(searchInput)) {
          product.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
          product.style.display = 'none';
        }
      });
    }

    // Function to apply filter on products
    function filterProducts() {
      const filterType = document.getElementById('filterType').value.toLowerCase();
      const filterBrand = document.getElementById('filterBrand').value.toLowerCase();
      const products = document.getElementsByClassName('product');
      Array.from(products).forEach(product => {
        const productType = product.dataset.type.toLowerCase();
        const productBrand = product.dataset.brand.toLowerCase();
        if ((filterType === 'all' || productType === filterType) && (filterBrand === 'all' || productBrand === filterBrand)) {
          product.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
          product.style.display = 'none';
        }
      });
    }

          // Function to fetch lanes and their active-products from server
  function fetchLanes() {
    fetch('fetch_activeproduct.php')
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Failed to fetch lanes');
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            if (data.success) {
                const lanes = data.lanes;
                updateLanesUI(lanes);
            } else {
                console.error('Error fetching lanes:', data.error);
                alert('Failed to fetch lanes. Please try again later.');
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error fetching lanes:', error);
            alert('Failed to fetch lanes. Please try again later.');
        });
  }

    // Function to update UI with lanes and their active-products
  function updateLanesUI(lanes) {
    const lanesContainer = document.getElementById('lanes');
    lanesContainer.innerHTML = ''; // Clear existing content

    lanes.forEach(lane => {
        const laneElement = document.createElement('div');
        laneElement.classList.add('lane');
        laneElement.textContent = `${lane['active-product']}`;
        lanesContainer.appendChild(laneElement);
        
    });
  }



    // Initialize products and lanes on page load
    window.onload = function () {
      generateLanes(); // Generate lanes when the page loads
      fetchProducts(); // Fetch products when the page loads
      fetchLanes(); // Fetch lanes and their active-products upon page load
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>


Thanks in advance
Best regards,
Kevin
My expected resault is that after selecting a product to the right i can click a lane and the product inside that lane should change with the selected product.

Please edit the question and provide more debugging details.  For example, when you say you think the issue is with Lanes.forEach(lane=>......, what exactly leads you to believe that's where the problem is? When you debug this line by line, at what point do you get a result you didn't expect (and exactly what did you get versus what you expected at that point in the code)?

Also, if the problem is with that iteration over lanes, it would be helpful if you provided more details about what the structure of data.lanes looks like.

Use console.log(lanes) to make sure the array contains what you expect.

You only add event listeners to the lanes when you call generateLanes() when the page first loads. This doesn't add listeners to the new lanes that are added by fetchLanes(). You should use event delegation instead of adding listeners to each lane individually. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508221/vanilla-javascript-event-delegation
